# How to get the answer of the calculation from one class to appear onto another class?

Tags: arrays, class, bubble-sort

Can anyone teach me the coding on how to to get the answer of this coding to appear onto another class?

```
 public class BubbleSort4 
 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        int intArray[] = new int[]{5,90,35,45,150,3};

        System.out.println("Array Before Bubble Sort");
        for(int i=0; i < intArray.length; i++)
        {
                System.out.print(intArray[i] + " ");
        }

        bubbleSort(intArray);

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Array After Bubble Sort");
        for(int i=0; i < intArray.length; i++)
        {
                System.out.print(intArray[i] + " ");
        }

 }

public static void bubbleSort(int[] intArray) 
{                            
        int n = intArray.length;
        int temp = 0;

        for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
        {
                for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++)
                {

                        if(intArray[j-1] > intArray[j])
                        {

                                temp = intArray[j-1];
                                intArray[j-1] = intArray[j];
                                intArray[j] = temp;
                        }

                }
        }    
}
}
```

Coding answer:
Array after Bubble Sort
5 90 35 45 150 3

Array After Bubble Sort
3 5 35 45 90 150

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change the structure of you class. Make the intArray a class field:

```
public class BubbleSort4 {
    static int intArray[] = new int[]{5,90,35,45,150,3};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
```

Have a method that returns the sorted array:

```
public static int[] getSortedArray() {
    bubbleSort(intArray);
    return intArray;
}
```

And now you can call `BubbleSort4.getSortedArray()` from any class, and the sorted array will be returned. Hope this helps.

Comment: didn't work. Kept getting 'illegal start of expression'

Comment: To me, it works fine. In which part do you get the error? How do you call `BubbleSort4.getSortedArray()` ? Also, make sure you close every bracket you open.